In Pyspark, when loading data into a dataframe, one of the fields in StructType is missing, which turns the whole StructType field into NULL
I have a column "data" in a parquet file.
This is what data contains:"{""col1"":123,""col2"":123,""col3"":13,""col4"":565.0, ""col5"":565.0}"
When col5 is missing, when I load data into dataframe, the whole "data" column is null. Even though col1, col2, col3 and col4 contain data..
   df = spark.read.parquet("/path/to/parquet_file")

    df.printSchema()
    df.show()

 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col3: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col4: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col5: string (nullable = true)


I tried specifying schema and casting data as string, but I keep getting casting error.
df = spark.read.schema(incomingSchema).parquet("/path/to/parquet_file")


You can go further in your debugging.
After reading the parquet file into a DF, extract the data column as a JSON string, and then parse each JSON string while handling missing fields.

Read file info DF:

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Whatever").getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.parquet("/path/to/parquet_file")


Define schema for JSON parsing:

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, LongType, DoubleType, StringType

incomingSchema = StructType([
    StructField("col1", LongType(), True),
    StructField("col2", LongType(), True),
    StructField("col3", LongType(), True),
    StructField("col4", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("col5", DoubleType(), True)
])


Extract fields from JSON while handling missing variables:

from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json

# Parse JSON string column
df = df.withColumn("data_parsed", from_json(col("data").cast("string"), incomingSchema))

# Replace nulls with appropriate values or retaining existing values
df = df.withColumn(
    "data_parsed",
    when(
        isnull(col("data_parsed.col1")) & isnull(col("data_parsed.col2")) & isnull(col("data_parsed.col3")) & isnull(col("data_parsed.col4")) & isnull(col("data_parsed.col5")),
        None
    ).otherwise(col("data_parsed"))
)

df = df.withColumn("col1", when(isnull(col("data_parsed.col1")), None).otherwise(col("data_parsed.col1")))
df = df.withColumn("col2", when(isnull(col("data_parsed.col2")), None).otherwise(col("data_parsed.col2")))
df = df.withColumn("col3", when(isnull(col("data_parsed.col3")), None).otherwise(col("data_parsed.col3")))
df = df.withColumn("col4", when(isnull(col("data_parsed.col4")), None).otherwise(col("data_parsed.col4")))
df = df.withColumn("col5", when(isnull(col("data_parsed.col5")), None).otherwise(col("data_parsed.col5")))

# Reconstruct StructType
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn(
    "data",
    F.struct("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5")
).drop("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "data_parsed")

This should allow you to handle each field in StructType correctly so that missing fields do not cause entire StructType field to become NULL.

I am still getting null. Maybe spark turns the whole column into null when loading data from parquet?
